# Getting repeated user.proactiveRefresh.user.proactiveRefresh..... and so on

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, infinite-loop

Basically, I am unsure of why firebase is hitting an active refresh in what seems to be an infinite loop. This is supposed to be code that gets user input from a form and sets the firebase 9 database to have a new post once the submit button is hit

```
export function create() {
createForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    // Initialize Firebase
   
    e.preventDefault();
    const Name = createForm["nameInput"].value;
    const Description = createForm["descriptionInput"].value;
    const Ingredients = createForm["ingredientsInput"].value;
    const Instructions = createForm["instructionsInput"].value;
    const Tags = createForm["tagInput"].value;
    const File = createForm["fileInput"].files[0];
    const TimeStamp = new Date().getTime();
    const User = auth.currentUser;
    const Uid = auth.currentUser.uid;

        //insert commented out section here if need
    const recipeRef = ref(db, "recipes");

    const newRecipeRef = push(recipeRef);

    if(User == null){
      window.location.href = "login.html";
      document.getElementById("create-form").reset();
    }
    set(newRecipeRef, {
      name: Name,
      description: Description,
      imageURL: File,
      ingredients: Ingredients,
      instructions: Instructions,
      tags: Tags,
      timeStamp: TimeStamp,
      uid: Uid,
      username: User,
    },
    function(error){
      if(error){
        console.error("Error adding document: " + error);
      } else {
        console.long("posted to database");
        alert(" Form submitted successfully!");
          document.getElementById("create-form").reset();
          window.location.href = "displayTest.html";
      }
    }
    
    );         
  });
   console.log("it worked");
 }
```

I am not super familiar with firebase right now, this is my first project with it. So I am so sorry if this is sloppy, but I also am at a total loss of what the code is getting caught up on

edit: This is the error I am getting. I forgot to include it.

caught Error: set failed: value argument path specified exceeds the maximum depth that can be written (32) or object contains a cycle in property 'recipes.-.username.proactiveRefresh.user.proactiveRefresh.user.proactiveRefresh.user.proactiveRefresh.user.proactiveRefresh.user.proactiveRefresh.user.proactiveRefresh.user.proactiveRefresh.user.proactiveRefresh.user.proactiveRefresh.user.proactiveRefresh.user.proactiveRefresh.user.proactiveRefresh.user.proactiveRefresh.user.proactiveRefresh.user'

Comment: It seems like the problem is this `const User = auth.currentUser;`. You probably wanted to do something like `const User = auth.currentUser.username;`. Firebase probably just don't allow complicated objects with circle properties.

Comment: hm ok I can try this. the reason I had set it to be auth.currentUser is that using the username method left me with a null value (which I have set to take back to login page) and, but the auth.currentUser at least had some value.